# IPv6 Validation and Ipv4 Validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am facing problem with ipv6 validations and ipv4 validations in JavaScript please help me

Advanced Thanks

Comment: I really wonder who upvotes questions that are as vague as this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this script
http://download.dartware.com/thirdparty/ipv6validator.js

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817698/ipv6-validation-and-ipv4-validation-in-javascript#comment-12509164) that this is a terrible question, but it is also one of the top results when searching for Javascript IP validation. I used [inet_pton() from php.js](http://phpjs.org/functions/inet_pton/) to validate IP addresses. It's only 46 lines of code including comments and works for both IPv4 and IPv6:

```
var address = "123.123.123.123";
if (inet_pton(address) !== false) {
    // Address is valid
}
```

Also, to see if an IP address belongs in the range between two IPs is very easy since you can compare the binary strings directly:

```
var address = "123.123.123.123";
var range_start = "123.1.1.1";
var range_end = "123.255.255.255";

if (inet_pton(address) >= inet_pton(range_start) &&
    inet_pton(address) <= inet_pton(range_end)
) {
    // Address is within the given range
}
```

If `range_start` and `range_end` come from user input, you should also verify that they are the same version because I don't think it makes much sense otherwise (correct me if I'm wrong). So I whipped together this quick function:

```
function same_ip_version(ip1, ip2) {
    var ipv4_pattern = /^(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.|$)){4}/;
    return ipv4_pattern.test(ip1) === ipv4_pattern.test(ip2);
}
```